# Cannot execute shell command with redirected multiline input using Python Paramiko

Tags: python, shell, unix, ssh, paramiko

I am using Paramiko to do the standard SSH into a box, run commands, and display the STDOUT to my terminal. Due to sudo rules, I SSH into a machine with my username and run `sudo /bin/su -s /bin/bash - <diff user account>`. In my script, I am passing the following command into Paramiko but the STDOUT does not show on my screen. I believe this is because the `sudo` command is opening a new shell and Paramiko is watching the STDOUT on the new shell.

The commands DO run as I have logged onto the box and see the command history. How do I get the STDOUT of the commands I am running to show on my terminal?

```py
import paramiko

def sshCommand(hostname, port, username, command, key_filename='/home/<my username>/.ssh/id_rsa'):
        sshClient = paramiko.SSHClient()
        sshClient.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        sshClient.connect(hostname=hostname, port=port, username=username, key_filename=key_filename)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = sshClient.exec_command(command, get_pty=False)
        output = stdout.readlines()
        print(output)

sshCommand('<servername>', 22, '<my username>', """sudo /bin/su -s /bin/bash - <diff username> << \'EOF\'
echo "Hello World"
EOF
""")
```

Comment: Does it work with a simpler command, like `sudo /bin/su -s /bin/bash - username echo foo`?

Comment: Nope. but from the server itself it does. I am looking in to the "invoke_shell" function for paramiko to see if that may work  invoke_shell(*args, **kwds)

    Request an interactive shell session on this channel. If the server allows it, the channel will then be directly connected to the stdin, stdout, and stderr of the shell.

Comment: We need [mcve] - so please reduce your code to the simplest example that still reproduces your problem.

Comment: Just reduced my code to the simplest example.

Comment: Does it work, if you specify the command directly on `su` command-line (not via a redirected input)?

Comment: No, the sudo permissions on the box do not allow for running commands that way. We sudo to the shared user and run the applications commands that way.

Comment: Would `echo echo foo | sudo /bin/su -s /bin/bash - username` work?

Comment: Yes, you sir are awesome! Not sure what's different in behavior but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that OpenSSH SSH server  can accept the `<< 'EOF'` shell construct on the "exec" channel.

But this should work:

```
echo echo "Hello World" | sudo /bin/su -s /bin/bash - <diff username>
```